# TcpClient performance on Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, tcpclient

I have encountered a problem with TcpClient running on an Android device. The issue is that reading from NetworkStream takes a lot of time. I use it to send bitmaps from server application (also written in C#) to my Android device (Nexus 9). I push 6000 bitmaps each of them around 1.4KB in size. That takes around 30 seconds to complete (5ms per bitmap). On the other hand I also implemented the same in Java and it takes 5 seconds to do the same (less than 1ms per bitmap)!

Are you aware of any issues regarding TcpClient in Xamarin.Android? I have to admit that this is very surprising as I have never had similar problems with Xamarin.

I pasted just a little code below so you can take a look if it is not me that messed up something. At the very bottom I also pasted Java code and as you can see it is very similar. Do you have any suggestions regarding this? I appreciate any feedback.

Here is the method that I use to receive bitmaps (this function runs asynchronously and is started through Task.Factory.StartNew()):

```
    private void HandleRequestBitmaps(TcpClient client, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (client == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("client");
        }

        var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        using (var stream = client.GetStream())
        {
            stream.WriteMessageWithLength(ServerCommand.PushBitmaps.ServerCommandToBytes(encoder));

            var initialMetadataBytes = stream.ReadMessageWithLength(client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            int[] initialMetadata;
            if (!TryParseMetadataMessage(initialMetadataBytes, encoder, 3, out initialMetadata))
            {
                BitmapReceiveEnd(this, new BitmapReceiveEndEventArgs(false));
                return;
            }

            BitmapsReceiveBegin(this,
                new BitmapsReceiveBeginEventArgs(initialMetadata[0], initialMetadata[1], initialMetadata[2]));

            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var messageBytes = stream.ReadMessageWithLength(client.ReceiveBufferSize);

                if (ServerCommand.PushBitmapsDone.Equals(messageBytes.BytesToServerCommand(encoder)))
                {
                    BitmapReceiveEnd(this, new BitmapReceiveEndEventArgs(true));
                    break;
                }

                int[] metadata;
                if (!TryParseMetadataMessage(messageBytes, encoder, 3, out metadata))
                {
                    BitmapReceiveEnd(this, new BitmapReceiveEndEventArgs(false));
                    return;
                }

                var bitmapBytes = stream.ReadMessageWithLength(client.ReceiveBufferSize);

                BitmapReceived(this,
                    new BitmapReceivedEventArgs(metadata[0], new Point(metadata[1], metadata[2]), bitmapBytes));
            }
        }
    }
```

Where TryParseMetadaMessage method looks like this:

```
    private static bool TryParseMetadataMessage(byte[] message, Encoding encoder, int expectedLength,
        out int[] metadata)
    {
        var messageString = encoder.GetString(message, 0, message.Length);
        var messageStringSeparated = messageString.Split('x');

        if (messageStringSeparated.Length != expectedLength)
        {
            metadata = new int[0];
            return false;
        }

        var parameteres = new List<int>();
        foreach (var messageStringPart in messageStringSeparated)
        {
            int value;
            if (!int.TryParse(messageStringPart, out value))
            {
                metadata = new int[0];
                return false;
            }

            parameteres.Add(value);
        }

        metadata = parameteres.ToArray();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also ReadMessage with length looks like this:

```
    public static byte[] ReadMessageWithLength(this Stream stream, int bufferSize = 2048)
    {
        if (stream == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");
        }

        var messageSizeBuffer = new byte[4];
        if (stream.Read(messageSizeBuffer, 0, messageSizeBuffer.Length) < 1)
        {
            return new byte[0];
        }

        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            Array.Reverse(messageSizeBuffer);
        }

        var totalBytesToRead = BitConverter.ToInt32(messageSizeBuffer, 0);
        if (totalBytesToRead < 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Number of bytes to read cannot be negative!");
        }

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int chunkBytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;

            while (
                (chunkBytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(totalBytesToRead - totalBytesRead, buffer.Length))) >
                0)
            {
                memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, chunkBytesRead);

                totalBytesRead += chunkBytesRead;
                if (totalBytesRead >= totalBytesToRead)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Now time for Java code. The function used to receive bitmaps:

```
public void requestBitmaps() {
    if (socket == null || !socket.isConnected()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Socket has to be initialized and connected to call this method!");
    }

    requestBitmapsThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                InputStream sis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                OutputStream sos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                writeMessageWithLength(sos, ServerCommand.PushBitmaps.getValueBytes());

                byte[] initialMetadataBytes = readMessageWithLength(sis, socket.getReceiveBufferSize());
                int[] initialMetadata = parseMetadataMessage(initialMetadataBytes, 3);
                if (initialMetadata == null) {
                    listener.onBitmapReceivedEnd(false);
                    return;
                }

                listener.onBitmapReceivedBegin(initialMetadata[0], initialMetadata[1], initialMetadata[2]);

                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    byte[] messageBytes = readMessageWithLength(sis, socket.getReceiveBufferSize());

                    if (ServerCommand.PushBitmapsDone.equals(ServerCommand.fromValueBytes(messageBytes))) {
                        listener.onBitmapReceivedEnd(true);
                        break;
                    }

                    int[] metadata = parseMetadataMessage(messageBytes, 3);
                    if (metadata == null) {
                        listener.onBitmapReceivedEnd(false);
                        break;
                    }

                    byte[] bitmapBytes = readMessageWithLength(sis, socket.getReceiveBufferSize());

                    listener.onBitmapReceived(metadata[0], metadata[1], metadata[2], bitmapBytes);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    requestBitmapsThread.start();
}
```

And also parseMetadataMessage method:

```
private int[] parseMetadataMessage(byte[] metadataBytes, int expectedLength) {
    String metadataString = new String(metadataBytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    String[] metadataStringSeparated = metadataString.split("x");

    if (metadataStringSeparated.length != expectedLength) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        int[] parameters = new int[metadataStringSeparated.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < metadataStringSeparated.length; i++) {
            parameters[i] = Integer.parseInt(metadataStringSeparated[i]);
        }
        return parameters;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And readMessageWithLength:

```
private byte[] readMessageWithLength(InputStream is, int bufferLength) throws IOException {
    byte[] messageLengthBuffer = new byte[4];
    if (is.read(messageLengthBuffer) < 0) {
        return null;
    }

    ByteBuffer messageLengthByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(messageLengthBuffer).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    int totalBytesToRead = messageLengthByteBuffer.getInt();
    if (totalBytesToRead < 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Total bytes to read cannot be less than 0!");
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapBytesBuffer = null;
    try {
        bitmapBytesBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
        int chunkBytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;

        while ((chunkBytesRead = is.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(totalBytesToRead - totalBytesRead, buffer.length))) > 0) {
            bitmapBytesBuffer.write(buffer, 0, chunkBytesRead);

            totalBytesRead += chunkBytesRead;
            if (totalBytesRead >= totalBytesToRead) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return bitmapBytesBuffer.toByteArray();
    } finally {
        if (bitmapBytesBuffer != null) {
            bitmapBytesBuffer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

If you have come this far, thanks for attention. I appreciate any feedback and I hope it will be possible to speed up the code.

Best regards,
Bartosz

Comment: Just a thought: AFAIK it is all becuase TcpClient is not native on Android but rather wrapper around java's API ... but I'm not sure ...

Comment: But because of this it would be 6 times slower? It is hard to believe.

Comment: It depends entirely on the implementation. And it's not entirely implausible that the Xamarin (or Mono? I don't really know where the implementation comes from) developers did not focus their efforts on making a really good `TcpClient` implementation.

Comment: For what it's worth, the code (at least the part posted) doesn't seem to have anything obviously wrong in it. Some minor optimizations could be made, such as dealing with endian more directly and pre-allocating the buffer for the `MemoryStream` (since you know the expected length). But I doubt those would affect whatever issue you're seeing.